# moodle "Can not initialise PHP session, please verify that your browser accepts cookies."

Tags: session, google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies, moodle

I'm trying to install MOODLE locally
and i face this problem

```
Can not initialize PHP session, please verify that your browser accepts cookies.
```

I'm trying to enable cookie (I'm using chrome) 
following these steps
https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61416

and I also tried to config php.ini
http://support.qualityunit.com/021373-How-To-Enable-Session-Support-for-PHP

but still can't solve it

anyone can help me?

```
php configuration <br/>
session
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   D:\EasyPHP-12.1/tmp D:\EasyPHP-12.1/tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS <br/>
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_ <br/>
session.use_cookies On  On <br/>
session.use_only_cookies    On  On <br/>
session.use_trans_sid   0   0 <br/>
```

Comment: moodle stores sessions in the database, but your probably having a problem with allowing cookies on your browser.

Comment: I allow already but still not working. I try appserv easyphp not work but only works in xampp

Comment: @HueiTan Kindly share the solution if you've found it. I'm facing the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Usually this is a php config problem where php can't write to the session folder.
The exact path and user vary by operating system but I'll attempt to summarize.

First we need to see if sessions are the problem but we need to know which config file php using and which path its saving sessions to.
To do that:

1. Make a new file in your moodle install folder called info.php,
2. add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
3. and save.
4. Send your browser to that page on your
   webserver.

This will show you a couple of things:

- "session.save_path" is where php is trying to save your sessions files.
- "APACHE_RUN_USER" is the user apache is running as.
- "Loaded Configuration File" will show you which file php is reading these
  settings from.

If your session.save_path is set, check the permissions of that folder. They should be owned by the web server user. Once you've fixed that, reload the moodle screen.

If your session.save_path is not set, set it to "/tmp/" for now.
This is a location which is always writable but isn't very secure.
Restart your web server and reload the moodle screen.

Comment: owned by web server (nginx, apache), or owned by php-fpm?

Comment: @datdinhquoc - I was assuming mod_php which means php is running under the web server user.
For php-fpm; Look for $_SERVER['USER']. This is the user php-fpm is running under. Your sessions should be writable by this user.

Answer (score 1):

Hy, I faced the same issue. I just clear the site data from the browser and work.