# Moodle - "Can not initialise PHP session, please verify that your browser accepts cookies."

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, moodle

I am unable install MOODLE in localhost as it gives following error:

`Can not initialize PHP session, please verify that your browser accepts cookies.`

I tried to find the solution but was unable to come up with any. I've also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328515/moodle-can-not-initialise-php-session-please-verify-that-your-browser-accepts), still I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the following answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328515/moodle-can-not-initialise-php-session-please-verify-that-your-browser-accepts

Comment: @AldoParadiso I've already mentioned that link in the question that I referred to that question and I am still unable to find a solution.

Comment: Oh, OK. Now I see the link:-)

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I've installed Moodle 4.1. php version 8.2 and getting the same issue 'Cannot initialise PHP session. Please verify that your browser accepts cookies.'

Answer (score 1):

I had a whitespace in my localhost URL path.  Removing it (and updating $CFG->wwwroot in config.php) fixed this issue for me.